# Mysql From enum to tinyint problems

Tags: mysql

I've got a table with

```
`terms_of_payment` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT ''
```

I run

```
ALTER TABLE `customer` 
CHANGE `terms_of_payment` `terms_of_payment` TINYINT( 1 ) 
     NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '';
```

and I found all my customers (with '0' value) set to 1 when I'm waiting 0

Could you explain me, what's the trouble, please ?

Bye

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Converting the `ENUM` to `TINYINT` might give unexpected results, as MySQL will actually already store your `ENUM` in the form of integers. To get the result you want, you should actually start by converting your column to a `CHAR(1)` and then go to `TINYINT(1)`.