# MySql - Strange behavior when altering field enum type to tinyint

Tags: php, mysql, sql, alter-table, alter

I'm updating all of my table fields with enum type to tinyint(1), but I'm seeing some strange behavior.

Say field_x type is `enum('0','1','2')`;

After altering the table (`ALTER TABLE a MODIFY field_x tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1`), fields with original value 0 now have 1, fields with original value 1 now have 2...

Does anybody know what is causing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql From enum to tinyint problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607763/mysql-from-enum-to-tinyint-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue is the how enum is stored in mysql

For `enum('0','1','2')` MySQL stores enum values internally as integer keys.

So for above indexes are

```
0 = 1
1 = 2
2 = 3
```

So when you alter the colum to `tinyint` then the saved values which are as string being converted to the corresponding indexes for `tinyint` and you are getting

```
1 for 0, 2 for 1 ....
```