# MySQL: turn enum to tinyint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with column that is enum with possible values 'Y' or 'N'. I want to set that to tinyint and convert all rows accordingly - set 'Y' to 1, and 'N' to 0. Could you please explain how to do that. Thanks

Comment: would you like to update the table or would you just like to get 1 and 0 when you select from the table instead of Y and N

Comment: update existing rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add options 0 and 1 to the ENUM.
2. Run QUERY (UPDATE [table] SET [column] = 1 WHERE [column] = 'Y') (and also for 'N')
3. Change type to INT(1)

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Going directly from an enum to a TINYINT(1) coerces the values in unexpected ways. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7607788/331791